# setting up classpath. javac is not recognized

Tags: java, javac

I am trying to run my java program from command line.

I read an article about setting up classpath, but I get an error of javac is
not recognized as internal or external command. What should I do? (I dont want to set a permanent CLASSPATH)
This is what I have done in my command line

```
D:\user> set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\1.7.0_07\bin

D:\user> cd testing

D:\user\testing> javac firstProgram.java
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Thank you

Comment: there's a space - try using quotes.

Comment: where should I use quotes? thank you

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\1.7.0_07\bin looks like
"C:\Program"
"Files\Java\1.7.0_07\bin" (two separate things)
so "C:\Program Files\Java\1.7.0_07\bin" is what @Tom is saying.

Comment: `set path=%path%;"C:\Program Files\Java\1.7.0_07\bin"`

Comment: after setting the path close cmd and try running again it might work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that the PATH is correct<sup>1</sup>, the most likely cause is that you have a JRE installation ... and a JRE doesn't include a java compiler.  You need a JDK installation if you want to compile from the command line.

(You can confirm this by looking in the `C:\Program Files\Java\1.7.0_07\bin` directory to see if it contains a `javac.exe` file.  A JRE won't ...)

> Where can I find the Java compiler to download..

You need to download one of the JDK installers; see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

---

<sup>1 - I don't think quotes are required in a PATH variable on Windows.  At least that's what various examples that Google found for me seem to imply.  But I've never really understood the logic behind quoting in Windows ...</sup>

Comment: sorry I am totally new to this. Where can I find the Java compiler to download.. Thank you

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. I checked it and I actually had jdk installed. I also checked the bin directory and it has javac.exe. But the command line still reports the same error. do u know wat cause the prblem? (I try to run the prgram using another command: java firstProgram.testing and it works. my java program is a package)

Comment: The problem happens because the command shell cannot find the `javac.exe` file.  Either 1) javac.exe is not in C:\Program Files\Java\1.7.0_07\bin; i.e. it is not where you have installed the JDK or 2) your PATH environment variable setting is incorrect.

Comment: Normally, you need quotation marks around paths that contain spaces. But [that is not the case with the PATH environment variable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/29/776926.aspx). Of course, it doesn't hurt to include the quotation marks anyway, so I usually do for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Its an issue related to **Program Files**.

First make sure that your JDK Folder is installed in **Program Files** or **Program Files(x86)** or any other folder.

Then you should use the path of bin folder in " ". Because command prompt does break the string at space. When you will write it in " " then it will take is as a whole String.

You try these commands

```
set path=%path%;"C:\Program Files\Java\1.7.0_07\bin"
```

or

```
set path=%path%;"C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\1.7.0_07\bin"
```

It might help you to get out of this.

Answer (score 0):

Better do it in Environmental variable and check it!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try below command is recognized from command prompt 
C:\Program Files\Java\1.7.0_07\bin\javac  ab.java

This is just to verify your javac

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can set the path temporary, meaning if you close and reopen "command prompt" you will have to set the path again.

Assuming the path is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin`

TYPE IN   ***C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin***   AND HIT ENTER 
that's it.

Answer (score 0):

The commands `D:\user> set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\1.7.0_07\bin` works well for me

Answer (score 0):

Adding few more information to this:

Please check the version of JDK and JRE installed on your computer. Recently I faced the same problem even after setting the PATH. It gives the error "javac - command is not recognised"

Solution is there must be similar versions of JDK as well as JRE

E.g.: JDK 1.7.75 along with JRE 1.7.75